# How to parse host string

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to parse host string ("asd.com:123" for example) to obtain domain name and port. It looks like node.js has build-in URL module just for this. However it doesn't work as I expect (maybe it's supposed to parse only fully-qualified URLs?). Is there any other way to perform this?

```js
var urlModule = require('url');
var stringToParse = 'asd.com:123';
var parseResult = urlModule.parse(stringToParse);
console.log(parseResult);
```

output:

```js
{ protocol: 'asd.com:',
slashes: null,
auth: null,
host: '123',
port: null,
hostname: '123',
hash: null,
search: null,
query: null,
pathname: null,
path: null,
href: 'asd.com:123' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, I think asd.com:123 is a valid URL is, as in for example the file URL file:*filename*

Can you simply add 'http://' to stringToParse?

```
var parseResult = urlModule.parse('http://' + stringToParse);
```